# SyntaxError: invalid syntax Python issue

Tags: python

i have a problem i want to recover the minimum and maximum Values in another function args.parse ....

so my question why `[minimum:maximum]` is a

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

as the minimum and maximum can be input by User

```
def Z(Y,minimum,maximum):
    Y = [minimum:maximum]
    return Y
```

Help please

Comment: What exactly do you expect `[minimum:maximum]` to be?

Comment: Were you trying to make `range(minimum, maximum)`?

Comment: minimum = int(args.min)  
    maximum = int(args.max)

Comment: i have a array [ 0.........................59887987] i want To show plot using matplotlib but Only beetween index chosen [minimum:maximum]

Comment: if Y is the list and minimum and maximum are the values, you probably need to do Y= Y[Y.index(minimum):Y.index(maximum)] (maximum excluded). If minimum and maximum are indices, just add Y.

Comment: Y=Y[minimum:maximum], is this what you want to do?

Comment: basically I want to extract the data from array   between 2 index max and min , the value of max and min it will be inputed

Comment: Y=Y[minimum:maximum], is this what you want to do?  Thanks Bro , the best answer ever =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand what you wanted to achieve but i think is one of the following 2:

1.return a continuous range of value between minimum and maximum. In this case you can use range and do not pass Y as input param.

```
def Z(minimum,maximum):
    Y = range(minimum, maximum)
    return Y

print Z(2,4)
```

2.you want to slice Y between value at index minimum and maximum. the use the following:

```
def Z(Y,minimum,maximum):
    Y = Y[minimum:maximum]
    return Y

Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]    
print Z(Y,2,4)
```

**from your comment i think you want to use the version 2.**
so you have simply forgot to put Y before [minimum:maximum]. you have to put Y to say that this is the variable to be sliced. have a nice explanation on how slice works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: YES. I think he wanted the second

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
Y = [minimum:maximum]
```

It should be a tuple or something else

```
Y = (minimum, maximum)
```

You can't create a datastructure in Python like this. It is a slice but can't be instantiated like this.

Comment: This is like an extended version of the wonderful SyntaxError given :)

Comment: Obviously it's wrong :) that's why there is an error